# Mobile Button Not Working (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using jQuery and Bootstrap. As mentioned in the below html, the mobile button doesn't expand.
I have already checked on this site regarding confirming the data-target but no luck.
Here is the code I have,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>name</title>
<meta name="description" content="name">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <!-- Navbar Header -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"> name </a>
    </div> <!-- End Navbar Header -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="lastName_OnlineSummary.pdf">PDF</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/username/">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/username">GitHub</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:username@users.github.com">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- End Navbar-collapse -->
  </div>  <!-- End Container -->
</nav> <!-- End Navbar -->

<!-- ... -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to load Bootstrap script **after** jQuery. That's because Bootstrap depends on jQuery and that script have to be loaded first, so Bootstrap's script can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load Bootstrap script after jQuery. That's because Bootstrap depends on jQuery and that script have to be loaded first, so Bootstrap's script can use it. **Like this:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```